# Linq-ToEntities DataSource Assignment Hangs in Winforms

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities, data-binding

I have a very typical linq-to-entities data binding in WinForms:

```
myGrid.DataSource = myEntities.entity
```

When it reaches that line of code it simply hangs. Similar assignment a different entity work fine elsewhere in the code. The database contains no more than 50 lines of data in all entities (it's a new project) so it's not waiting on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I may have found the solution. I had an entity we'll call C, which linked entities A and B together as a join table. I decided A and B could be linked directly. Apparently this messed up the internal Linq logic and binding to either A or B then hung. When I removed C the binding to A and B started working.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if it's asp.net or windows forms... If it's a asp.net client you are trying to databind I would recommend sending the results to a List before assigning it to any datasource.

Comment: Winforms. Interestingly, I may have found the solution.  I had an entity we'll call C, which linked entities A and B together as a join table.  I decided A and B could be linked directly. Apparently this messed up the internal Linq logic and binding to either A or B then hung.  When I removed C the binding to A and B started working.

Comment: Navigational properties can be a pain in the ?$$ at times :)